# Como se refresca un .navigate?

Tags: angular, typescript

En el componente navbar tengo esta función que se ejecuta en el `click` del botón buscar o bien en el `keyup.enter` del input buscar:

```
  buscarShip( text: string ) {
    this.SearchRouter.navigate( ['/buscar', text ] );

  }
```

En el **OnInit** del componente buscar de destino se ejecuta este código:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.searchText = params['text'];

    })
    this.doBuscar( this.searchText );

  }
```

Todo funciona perfectamente en la 1ª búsqueda, la URL sería por ejemplo "http://localhost:4200/buscar/star" y se mostrarían los resultados correspondientes.

En la 2ª en cambio, a pesar de que cambia la URL correctamente como por ejemplo "http://localhost:4200/buscar/tie", no modifica los resultados, hace falta hacer un F5 para actualizar el navegador.

**Un console.log no entra en el OnInit**.

Si después de la 1ª búsqueda cambio de página y hago una 2ª búsuqeda, en estas condiciones si funciona.

Es como si al estar en la misma página ya no se ejecute el .navigate, no se si hay alguna manera de forzar que entre, que refresque, ...

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo tengo solucionado, he cambiado este código del **app.routes.ts**:

```
export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

por este otro:

```
export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
  });
```

Gracias